# How to use TypeScript in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and AngularJS. I understand AngularJS and TypeScript in general when considering them separately, but I do not understand how I would connect the two.

Some front-end frameworks ([like Angular 2+](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration) and [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#typescript)) have default tooling to integrate with TypeScript, but I do not see the same for AngularJS.

How would I set up a new AngularJS project to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript?

Comment: You mean Angular 1? Because Angular 2 is already in Typescript... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: **Edited for reopening:** Tried to edit question to make it explicitly ask for how to integrate AngularJS (Angular 1) with TypeScript, as AngularJS does not integrate easily out of the box as React and Angular 2+ do. I believe that matches the original intent, and is a reasonably focused query.

Answer (score 3):

**Angular2**

Angular2 is already in typescript. Following the angular2 quick start is the perfect way.

**Angular1.x with Typescript**

This is a [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020132046/https://tech.ovoenergy.com/angular-typescript/) that I used to follow to upgrade angular1.X from javascript to typescript.

**Typescript**

[Knowledge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) about typescript is also important.